# how do I control the position of fixed elements in css

Tags: css

I have two divs, I'll call them div1 and div2, as in this screenshot:

[image]

Both divs are `position:fixed`.

I want to layer div 2 over the top of div 1. I thought z-index would solve this, but I can't get it working.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7w3wsg7/)

```css
#one {
    height: 166px;
    right: 0;
    background:red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}
#two {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 215px;
    background:blue;
    height: 220px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

**NOTE: MY div 2 is coming very first on html document**

Comment: What do you mean by "upside"?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: upside means to make it on TOP

Comment: The word "in front" is probably least ambiguous.

Comment: can you post your code please

Comment: can you post html code as well

Comment: I think what he is looking for is `top: 0;`

Comment: Also you dont have to use float when you are using position fixed

Comment: @Mr.Alien  I just want to make DIV 2 in front of DIV 1...that's all

Comment: please can you make fiddle

Comment: Are you sure that z-index doesn't do what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/39tkwpsv/

Comment: is this output wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion http://jsfiddle.net/z7w3wsg7/

Comment: Use `z-index` for your elements, [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z7w3wsg7/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to play with z-index, just put `div#two` before `div#one` in your markup. This naturally layers both divs correctly.

[Your fiddle changed](http://jsfiddle.net/b2b0r0wc/).

Note that ids cannot start with a numeral if you want to target them with CSS.

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
#two {
    position:fixed;
    margin-left: 250px;
    width: 215px;
    background:blue;
    height: 220px;
}
#one {
    height: 166px;
    right: 0;
    background:red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="one"></div>
```